# Printing the exact same format as it was read by stdin

Tags: java, arrays, string, bigdecimal, selection-sort

I'm a beginner at Java and I'm stuck with a problem. The problem says:

> Given an array, s, of n real number strings, sort them in descending order — but wait, there's more! Each number must be printed in the exact same format as it was read from stdin, meaning that .1 is printed as .1, and 0.1 is printed as 0.1. If two numbers represent numerically equivalent values (e.g., ), then they must be listed in the same order as they were received as input).

I've written the following code:

```
'public static void main(String []args){
    //Input
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    String []s=new String[n+2];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        s[i]=sc.next();
    }
    sc.close();
    //TypeCasting
    BigDecimal[] deci = new BigDecimal[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        deci[i] =new BigDecimal(s[i]);
    }
    //Write your code here//SelectionSort
    for(int i =0; i<n-1; i++){
        for(int j=i; j<n; j++){
            int minIndex = i;
            if(deci[j].compareTo(deci[minIndex])>0){
                minIndex = j;
            } 
            BigDecimal temp = deci[i];
            deci[i] = deci[minIndex];
            deci[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        s[i] = (deci[i]).toString();
    }
    //Output
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
}`
```

`Sample Input:  9 -100 50 0 56.6 90 0.12 .12 02.34 000.000`
`Sample Output: 90 56.6 50 02.34 0.12 .12 0 000.000 -100`
`My Output:     90 56.6 50 2.34 0.12 0.12 0 0.000 -100`

Please help me how to print exactly the same format as asked using Selection Sort, which i used above.

Comment: Why are you writing your own sorting code? There are tons of sort routines already available to you.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I was new to Java kind of learning, haven't learnt them yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort `String[] s` at the same time as `BigDecimal[] deci`. This will allow you to output the original strings read form `System.in`, rather than somehow converting the `BigDecimal` objects back to their original strings.

You should be aware that your code does implement a selection sort, however it does not implement a *stable* selection sort. That is, *"If two numbers represent numerically equivalent values (e.g., ), then they must be listed in the same order as they were received as input."*
For example:

```
Sample Input:  6 .1 1 0.1 10 00.1 2
Expected Output: 10 2 1 .1  0.1 00.1
Your Output:     10 2 1 .1 00.1  0.1
```

A stable selection sort can be implemented by either, using an array and inserting the next value at its index and shifting the remaining elements. Or by using a `LinkedList` and adding the next value to the beginning of the unsorted portion.

Here is an implementation of the *insert and shift* approach. Instead of inserting and shifting right, I just swapped `deci[]` elements left until they are in the correct index.

```
static String[] selectionSortStable(BigDecimal[] deci, String[] s, int n) {
    //Write your code here //SelectionSort
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            int minIndex = i;
            
            if(deci[j].compareTo(deci[minIndex]) >= 0) {
                minIndex = j;
            } else {
                continue; // don't need to swap already sorted elements
            }
            
            // in order to ensure a stable sort, we need to swap unsorted
            // elements until deci[minIndex] is in deci[i]
            for(int k = minIndex; k > i; k--) {
                BigDecimal bdtmp = deci[k];
                deci[k] = deci[k - 1];
                deci[k - 1] = bdtmp;
                
                // sort the array of string representations at the same time
                String stmp = s[k];
                s[k] = s[k - 1];
                s[k - 1] = stmp;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Input
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    String[] s = new String[n+2];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s[i] = sc.next();
    }
    sc.close();
    //TypeCasting
    BigDecimal[] deci = new BigDecimal[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        deci[i] = new BigDecimal(s[i]);
    }
    
    s = selectionSortStable(deci, s, n);

    // now just output the sorted string array 's'
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(s[i] + " ");
    }
    
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class Data {

        int order;
        double value;
        String str;
    }

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        scan.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

        Comparator<Data> sortByValueDescThenByOrderAsc = (one, two) -> {
            int res = Double.compare(two.value, one.value);
            return res == 0 ? Integer.compare(one.order, two.order) : res;
        };

        String[] nums = scan.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        List<Data> res = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.str = nums[i];
            data.order = i;
            data.value = Double.parseDouble(data.str);
            res.add(data);
        }

        res.sort(sortByValueDescThenByOrderAsc);

        System.out.println(res.stream().map(data -> data.str).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
    }
}
```